# How to incorporate drake's optimization toolboxes with mujoco-py simulator?

Tags: python-3.x, drake

The problem is as following: suppose a single MuJoCo simulation is conducted with input parameters A and B, and the simulation outputs a single output value V. MuJoCo gets a "float" value of A and B, runs the simulation and then outputs V.

The goal of the optimization is to minimize the value V by adjusting the 2 input parameters A and B.

How can we incorporate pydrake’s optimization code (e.g. prog = MathematicalProgram()), with the MuJoCo simulation?

For this case, the output value V cannot be directly written with the parameters A and B, since 
 MuJoCo is sort of an external "black-box". Moreover, since MuJoCo is sort of a "black-box", the gradient information of output V cannot be provided.

Would there be any workaround for this?

Any small helps/comments will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have the gradient, then I suggest to use a black box optimizer. One choice is [nevergrad](https://github.com/facebookresearch/nevergrad) which contains various black-box optimizers. Note that you don't need to use drake's MathematicalProgram to call nevergrad. You just need to write a function which takes in A and B, and the evaluates the output using MuJoCo.

Comment: Hello Hongkai Dai. Thank you very much for your comment. 
It is great to receive a comment from a person who've I only encountered via papers :) 
Thank you again. I will definitely try your recommendation. Stay safe and healthy!

Comment: Great, let us know if you encounter any problems using drake. Stay safe and healthy!